# Runing mysqldump from java code won't dump triggers

Tags: java, triggers, backup, mysql

This is how i make mysql dumps from java

```
public static boolean mysqlDump(String destination){
File back=new File("tempsdfsdf.fdr");
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
FileWriter fw=null; 
try { 
    fw = new FileWriter(back); 
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    return false;
} 
Process child; 
try {
    child = rt.exec("mysqldump -h"+generals.DATABASE_SERVER+" -u"+DATABASE_USER+" -p"+DATABASE_PASS+" --single-transaction --routines databasename -r"+destination);
    InputStream in = child.getInputStream(); 
    InputStreamReader xx = new InputStreamReader(in,"utf8"); 
    char[] chars=new char[1024]; 
    int ibyte=0; 
    while((ibyte=xx.read(chars))>0) 
    { 
    fw.write(chars); 
    } 
    fw.close(); 
    Utils.deleteFile(back);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FRMTestare.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

The dump file is "destination",but i must simulate writing of InputStream() to a file to ensure that "destination" file is fully created when threat ends so that i can zip-it in another threat.Anyway this is not important!
My question is why when i run the command in cmd is dumping triggers but when i run the same command using Runtime.exec the triggers are not dumped .
  Sorry ,the code i a mess but i lost all day changing it to dump triggers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the arguments to mysqldump are the same for when you run them in two different environments, the difference must be in the permissions of the users you are using.

Check what user the commands run as (by using SHOW PROCESSLIST in another window while the mysqldumps are running) and that should show the difference and point the way to the solution: change the user or change the privileges of the user you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you explicity used `--routines` also try `--triggers`. You are probably seeing differences because of the way various defaults file are discovered and processed are different in your shell vs. from the JDK. It's probably not worth the effort of tracking it down. The explicit `--triggers` should work.